# Python: Unexpected predicted vs actual plot for regression models

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, seaborn

I have 3 regression models: Linear regression, Random Forest, and ANN.

Trying to compare them, I am plotting two plots: residuals and actual vs predicted.

Overall, the residuals suggest that most models predict the data well as they have a symmetric shape and follow the horizontal line. However, when evaluating the actual vs predicted, none of the models nearly follow the 45 degree line (suggesting perfect prediction). What am I doing wrong? Please see the relevant code below:

```
# Separate features from the label (add .values) to use arrays instead of dataframes
X = dataset2.iloc[:, 0:-1]
y = dataset2.iloc[:, -1]

# Split into training and testin sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

# Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Train OLS ####################################
ols_regressor = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()

# Predictions
y_pred_ols_test = ols_regressor.predict(X_test)
y_pred_ols_train = ols_regressor.predict(X_train)


# Train RF ####################################
rf = RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=False,
                          max_depth=100,
                          max_features=3,
                          min_samples_leaf=1,
                          min_samples_split=5,
                          n_estimators=800)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predictions
y_pred_rf_test = rf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_rf_train = rf.predict(X_train)

# Train RF ####################################
# ... TRAIN NN WITH KERAS AND TENSORFLOW ...

y_pred_nn_test = ann.predict(X_test)
y_pred_nn_train = ann.predict(X_train)
```

Here I am plotting the residuals:

```
fig, axes =plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(8,12))
fig.suptitle('Residuals', fontweight="bold", fontsize=15)

# OLS #######################################
axes[0] = sns.residplot(ax=axes[0], x=y_pred_ols_test, y=y_test, data=dataset, 
                          lowess=True,
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})
axes[0].set_xlim([-0.0050, 0.0005])
axes[0].set_ylim([-0.03, 0.03])
axes[0].set_title('Linear Regression')
axes[0].set_xlabel(' ')
axes[0].set_ylabel('Residuals')

# Random Forest ###############################
axes[1] = sns.residplot(ax=axes[1], x=y_pred_rf_test, y=y_test, data=dataset, 
                          lowess=True, 
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})
axes[1].set_xlim([-0.016, 0.006])
axes[1].set_ylim([-0.03, 0.03])
axes[1].set_title('Random Forest')
axes[1].set_xlabel(' ')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Residuals')

# Neural Network ###############################
axes[2] = sns.residplot(ax=axes[2], x=y_pred_nn_test, y=y_test, data=dataset, 
                          lowess=True,
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})

axes[2].set_xlim([-0.018, -0.009])
axes[2].set_ylim([-0.03, 0.03])
axes[2].set_title('Artificial Neural Network)')
axes[2].set_xlabel('Predicted values')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Residuals')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Then I plot the predicted vs actual plot:

```
fig, axes =plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(8,12))

fig.suptitle('Predicted vs Actual', fontweight="bold", fontsize=15)

# OLS #######################################
axes[0] = sns.regplot(ax=axes[0], x=y_pred_ols_test, y=y_test, 
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})
x0 = -0.00415
x1 = 0.00025
y0 = -0.03
y1 = 0.03
# Plot 45 degree line
axes[0].plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], ls="--", c="grey")
# # Axes Scale
axes[0].set_xlim([x0, x1])
axes[0].set_ylim([y0, y1])
# Labels
axes[0].set_title('Linear Regression')
axes[0].set_xlabel('')
axes[0].set_ylabel('True values')

# Random Forest ###############################
axes[1] = sns.regplot(ax=axes[1], x=y_pred_rf_test, y=y_test, 
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})
x0 = -0.0125
x1 = 0.0045
y0 = -0.03
y1 = 0.03
# Plot 45 degree line
axes[1].plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], ls="--", c="grey")
# Axes Scale
axes[1].set_xlim([x0, x1])
axes[1].set_ylim([y0, y1])
axes[1].set_title('Random Forest')
axes[1].set_xlabel(' ')
axes[1].set_ylabel('True values')

# NN #########################################
axes[2] = sns.regplot(ax=axes[2], x=y_pred_nn_test, y=y_test, 
                          color='darkcyan',
                          scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, 
                          line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1, 'alpha': 0.8})
x0 = -0.0175
x1 = -0.0092
y0 = -0.03
y1 = 0.03
# Plot 45 degree line
axes[2].plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], ls="--", c="grey")
# Axes Scale
axes[2].set_xlim([x0, x1])
axes[2].set_ylim([y0, y1])
axes[2].set_title('Artificial Neural Network')
axes[2].set_xlabel('Predicted values')
axes[2].set_ylabel('True values')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Theoretically, the actual vs predicted plot should be good right? Considering that the residuals plot is symmetric and horizontal. What am I missing here?

For the actual vs predicted I also tried using sns.scatterplot() but it was the same really...

Comment: You are not plotting a 45 degree dashed line. Afaik, this data `x0 = -0.0175 x1 = -0.0092 y0 = -0.03 y1 = 0.03` does not represent a 45 degree line. Edit: just noticed you're using different values for each plot. 45 degree line is not one that 'looks' like it, but where `y_true = y_pred`

Comment: How can I plot this correctly?

Comment: Did it with: ```axes[1].plot(y_test, y_test, ls='--', c='grey')```